# MYSQL schema keeps getting dropped

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, database-schema

I have a spring-boot application running using docker on a Ubuntu server, with MYSQL DB running on the server itself not in a docker image. The schema I am using for the spring-boot app keeps getting deleted randomly and I always have to restore it using backed up dump. I cannot determine the reason behind this weird issue. I tried googling this issue and I could not find anything about this issue.

What could possibly cause a DB to be dropped?!?

It is random like once a week! may be more than that. I cannot even track that.

My application.yml has this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url:  jdbc:mysql://localhost/schemaname?useSSL=false
    username: username
    password: password
    tomcat:
      validation-query: SELECT 1
      test-on-borrow: true

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Can you search your project files for strings `ddl-auto` and `hbm2ddl`?

Comment: Why the docker tag since your mysql isn't running in docker?

Comment: @BMitch Docker tag because I started having this issue when I started using Docker may be someone has faced this with docker.

Comment: @RandallFlagg as you can see from my application.yml I use ddl-auto: update. Which updates the table whenever any change is made. I don't have hbm2ddl anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `ddl-auto` for a production app.

Quote from [Java Persistence with Hibernate](https://www.manning.com/books/java-persistence-with-hibernate).

> WARNING: We've seen Hibernate users trying to use SchemaUpdate to
>   update the schema of a production database automatically. This can
>   quickly end in disaster and won't be allowed by your DBA.

This option is intended to be used only for development.

If you don't want to manually run your SQL migrations, you should consider tools like flyway or liquibase.

Comment: I turned it off on production and I am testing it right now. Yes I read that everywhere that I am not supposed to do that on prod.